# How to retrieve data using mongoose ine ejs page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to display articles stored in my blogs collection using mongoose in ejs page. But got stuck due to following error.

blogs.js -

```
            var mongoose = require('mongoose');
            var blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
                title   :   String,
                description :   String,
                time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
                details : String  

            });
            module.exports = mongoose.model('blogs',blogSchema);
```

routes.js

```
              app.get('/blogs',function(req, res) {
                //blogs.find();
                blogs.find({})
                .sort({'date': -1})
                .exec(function(err, events) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

            res.render('blogs.ejs', {
                    blogs : blogs
                });
            });
```

blogs.ejs

```
                <div class="grid" id="lvc-past-blogs-container">
                <div class="col-1-1">
                    <div id="past-speakers">
                    <h2><i>-PAST SPEAKERS</i></h2>
                    <% for (var i = 1; i < blogs.length; i++) { %>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= blogs[i].description %></a> (<%= blogs[i].time %> | <%= blogs[i].details %>)</li>
                    </ul>
                    <% }; %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

error

[image]

Comment: in blogs.ejs, you're starting your loop at i=1. arrays are zero indexed in javascript. so if your array only has one item, the first iteration of the loop you're accessing blogs[1] which is undefined.

Comment: May I know why you are passing blog collection in your result instead of events(find data) ?

Comment: Yeah..I got it now. It was my bad. It should be blogs not events. Thanx for pointing out my mistake. Now it's working fine @PankajJatav

Comment: Your welcome my friend